# cleanup caches changes file permissions

Tags: permissions, cache

My site (on a VPS running CPanel, CiviCRM 5.49.3, Drupal 9.3.14) currently has file permission issues. This hasn't always been the case, and I don't know the in initial cause for the problem.

Due to permission issues the caches are inaccessible and the site functionality is very limited.

I have come across advice for a script that set permissions in a way that supports the site functionality.

```
cd /home/user/www-sangha-drupal/web/
chown -R user:nobody .
find . -type d -exec chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o= '{}' \;
find . -type f -exec chmod u=rw,g=r,o= '{}' \;

cd /home/user/www-sangha-drupal/web/sites
find . -type d -name files -exec chmod ug=rwx,o= '{}' \;
for d in ./*/files
do
   find $d -type d -exec chmod ug=rwx,o= '{}' \;
   find $d -type f -exec chmod ug=rw,o= '{}' \;
done
```

the result is in paths such as

```
sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn
sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c
```

this produces this kind of permission:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 user nobody  7785 May 28 23:08 crm-l10n.8a45e015fbdc223596bebbac430cb078.js
-rw-rw---- 1 user nobody 10751 May 28 23:08 crm-menubar.d91a640f1e3a566248597efb8795f11b.css

-rw-rw---- 1 user nobody   202 May 28 23:25 .htaccess
```

respectively.

When I cleanup caches, this permission changes to

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nobody  7785 May 28 23:08 crm-l10n.8a45e015fbdc223596bebbac430cb078.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nobody 10751 May 28 23:08 crm-menubar.d91a640f1e3a566248597efb8795f11b.css

-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nobody   202 May 28 23:25 .htaccess
```

Whereupon the the site doesn't work very well at all, as you might guess.

Here: [https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4144/civicrm-does-not-have-permission-to-write-temp-files-on-new-server][1]
it is suggested to modify

```
/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

I have tried updating what might be the right instance of this file (there are several with CPanel, so that makes it less certain), and restarting PHP-FPM server each time.

I have tried

```
listen.acl_users = apache,nginx,user
listen.acl_users = apache,nginx,nobody,user
```

Neither of these have changed the behavior or functioning of the site, as described above.

Please any suggestions for how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when you clear cache as user other than the web server user ( like running drush cr as your own user ).
I would do the following.

Substitute Apache and YourUser as your Webster and other user in your system (assumes Linux).

1. First correct current permissions

   Sudo chown -R Apache:YourUser

   Sudo chmod -R ug+rw /path-to-Drupal-root-/web/sites/yourSite/files/civicrm/
2. Now, clear cache as we server user or via weblink and not commandline
   If you want use commandline , run as Apache :: sudo -u apache drush cr..

Comment: one thing I wonder about is CPanel usage of 'nobody' instead of 'apache'.  This being the case, would it be correct to use this modified instruction from you: `sudo chown -R nobody:user` ?

Comment: Cpanel has its own file icon where you can fix permissions. It’s been while since I used it.  Search their help articles on webserver permissions

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my problem by changing the php apache module from mod_mpm_event which uses 'nobody'; to mod_mpm_itk which uses 'user'